# First "Simple" Audio Player Application

Tags: iphone

Can anybody please tell me how to implement an audio player application in an iPhone? I am pretty new to iPhone development and I am just starting to learn the tricks of the trade.

PS: I need sample code!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play your own sounds, the [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) class. If you want to play media from the iPod library, see [MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller).